# How to replace NaN in an array with the next closest number?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, nan

Let me describe my issue in greater detail. I'm logging a fair amount of data from an experiment into two arrays: `count` and `tick`. These two arrays are then used to calculate `factor` like so:

```
factor = (diff(tick)./diff(count))
```

Since this is raw data, it is not guaranteed to produce "nice" numbers. In fact, what I get is an array similar to `factor = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NaN, NaN, NaN, 3, 3, 4, 5, NaN, ... ]`.

I need to further manipulate this data with functions that can't handle NaN's. What I would like to do is search for NaN in `factor` and replace it with the next closest number.

Searching for the NaN values in the array and replacing them is not an issue. For instance, all I would have to do is `a(isnan(a)) = some value`. However, in order to keep the data consistent, I want to replace each *individual* NaN with the closest value that is not NaN.

My initial thought was to loop through the array, look for NaN, and then enter another for loop until it finds a valid number, and replace the NaN with this number.

This will more than likely work, but my concern is efficiency. My arrays can be in the mega bytes. Is there a better way to accomplish what I need?

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Comment: What is the *most meaningful* number to substitute?  Usually it is zero.

Comment: That is true, however, this data supposedly follows a logarithmic curve - and this is only one aspect of a calculation that should never equal zero (this factor is a scalar). I had the same thought, but I realized I needed to try to approximate the surrounding valid values.

Comment: If the result is NaN, you're already being told that the result cannot be represented in floating point.  Any approximation is therefore going to be wrong.

Comment: My concern is not whether the result can be represented in floating point. The data I'm collecting is valid. When I do `diff(a)./diff(b)`, there will be places where I will get `NaN`. In terms of my data, this means there is identical data in two consecutive indices. This is expected. I therefore want to simply take the closest number to the current index in order to approximate  the data at that index. To be specific, my data shouldn't tell me, at this microsecond your speed is 200m/s, then at the next microsecond, your speed is 0m/s, and then immediately 200m/s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach 1: Using `bsxfun`+`abs`+`min`**

**Code**

```
%// Input
factor = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NaN, NaN, NaN, 3, 3, 4, 5, NaN, 6]

%// Indices of NaNs
t1 = find(isnan(factor)); 

%// Indices of non-NaNs
t2 = find(~isnan(factor));

%// Get index for each NaN index that is closest, with a tie-case 
%// (closest non-NaN number being at equal distance on either side) 
%// selecting the left one
[~,ind1] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus,t1,t2'))); %//'

%// Replace NaNs with the closest non-NaNs
factor(t1) = factor(t2(ind1))
```

**Output (on code-run)**

```
factor =
     2     3     4     5     6   NaN   NaN   NaN     3     3     4     5   NaN     6
factor =
     2     3     4     5     6     6     6     3     3     3     4     5     5     6
```

**Approach 2: Using 1-D interpolation with 'nearest' option**

**Code**

```
%// Input
factor = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NaN, NaN, NaN, 3, 3, 4, 5, NaN, 6]

%// Index array for factor
x = 1:numel(factor);

%// Indices of NaNs
t2 = find(~isnan(factor)); 

%// Replace NaNs with the closest non-NaNs
factor = interp1(x(t2),factor(t2),x,'nearest')
```

**Output (on code-run)**

```
factor =
     2     3     4     5     6   NaN   NaN   NaN     3     3     4     5   NaN     6
factor =
     2     3     4     5     6     6     3     3     3     3     4     5     6     6
```

Please note that in case of a tie (as discussed earlier), it chooses the right one instead of the left one as in the previous approach. Also note that this approach would only work if the first and last elements of `factor` aren't `NaNs`.

Finally, a suggestion that try to avoid variable names same as in-built MATLAB function names. In this case, `factor` is one such name.

Comment: +1 And I was right now typing the `interp1` approach, so I'd give you +2 if I could :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Appreciate it :) Yeah I guess `interp` approach could be faster for large datasets.